# SQL Count Years on FromDATE to ToDate fields

Tags: sql

Suppose i have

```
> ID              FromDate          ToDate 
> --              --------           -------
> 1               01/01/2005         30/6/2007
> 2               01/01/2008         31/12/2009
```

I want to count the years that are included on this 2 rows. Here is 1,5 years for the first row + 2 years from second row = Total of 3,5 years. How can i do this with SQL?

Comment: Using year and month DATEDIFF (uses end of year/month boundaries) gives row 1 = 2 years/29 months, row 2 = 1 year/23 months. Wher do you get 1.5/2 years from please?

Comment: what SQL flavor are you using? SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: Don't forget leap years...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123727/sql-count-years-on-fromdate-to-todate-fields/1123864#1123864

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using 365.25 for the days in the SQL DateDiff function to avoid issues with leap year.

```
select 
  SUM((DATEDIFF(d, FromDate, ToDAte)) / 365.25) as 'years-count'
from 
  mytableofdates
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Oracle:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SUM(MONTHS_BETWEEN(t.todate, t.fromDate)) / 12, 1)
  FROM TABLE t
```

The second parameter in TRUNC is the number of decimal places - the query, as is, would be to one decimal place.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(FromDate,ToDate)), '%Y')+0 AS age
```

found solution here http://goharsahi.wordpress.com/2007/08/18/calculating-age-from-date-of-birth-in-mysql/

Comment: How does this relate to the question?  You are not referring to the columns in the question nor addressing how to combine data from multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate)

Select ID, DATEDIFF(mm,StartDate,EndDate)/12
from YourTable

this should give the result your after.

Edit: Assuming SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

I think you have you calculations wrong - the first should be 2.5 years? If so this seems to give a decent approximation of what you want (again in SQL server)

```
create table YearDiff(ID int, fromDate datetime, toDate datetime)
go
insert into YearDiff values (1, '2005-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2007-06-30 00:00:00.000')
insert into YearDiff values (2, '2008-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2009-12-31 00:00:00.000')
select sum((datediff(ww, fromdate, todate)) / 52.0)  from YearDiff
```